# In PHP how do I send form data to a page but direct the user to another when he clicks the submit button?

Tags: php, html

Take this simple form as an example:

```
<form method="post" action="reports.php">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="email_address">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I want it to send the input fields data to the `reports.php` page but I want it to direct the user to the page `uploads.php` when he clicks the `"Submit"` button.

Using `header("Location: uploads.php")` on `reports.php` page is not an option because `reports.php` gathers the form data into a table for everyone to see. In the `uploads.php` page, the user will upload files that will also be visible on `reports.php` table.

How do I do this?

Comment: So you're showing some data on the `reports.php` page and you also want the redirect to happen? What's the use of showing the data on the page then if you want the user to be taken to another page?

Comment: _“is not an option because reports.php gathers the form data into a table for everyone to see”_ – well then _don’t_ make it do that, or use a different script to process the form data, that does not display the data publicly. Or, process the form data directly in your uploads.php, maybe depending on a condition, such as if the form send a specific parameter name, and let the script show whatever the user is supposed to see next afterwards – then you don’t need to redirect around in the first place.

Comment: use ajax to submit the form data to `reports.php` and use the callback function within the ajax request to redirect to `uploads.php`

Comment: Why? What's the point in having two pages?

Comment: It's how the code is done. I can't change it, it's not mine. I was just asked to add somethings and I am having trouble with this specific matter. I do not know AJAX and don't have enought time to study it.

Comment: Well if you can’t change the code _at all_, then you can not implement what you are asking for here either.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the method used in request to `reports.php` is `POST`, and redirect the user.

```
<?php
# reports.php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // process the data

    header("Location: ...");
    exit;
}
```

Or you can simply create a `add_report.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

You could add "on form submit" event with javascript.

When the submit button is clicked - collect the form data with javascript and send it where is necessary. When the ajax worked - redirect the user to the desired page with javascript.

A complete example would be smth like:

for html

```
<form method="post" id="my_form">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="email_address">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

for javascript

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $('#my_form').on('submit', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var url = 'reports.php?' + $(this).serialize();
       $.get(url, function(){
           window.location.href = 'uploads.php';
       });
   })
})
</script>
```

more info can be found here:
https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

You need to refactor your code.

It sounds like your use cases are:

1. GET to uploads: Show uploads form
2. POST to somewhere: Add to reports and then show uploads form
3. GET to reports: Show reports list
4. POST to reports: Add to reports and then show uploads form

Don't worry about making the "somewhere" be the reports file.

Separate out the "Add to reports" code into a function (or functions) and put them into a file of their own.

Then include that file in both reports and uploads.

Make the upload form submit to uploads and then call the "Add to reports" function.

Do something similar in reports.